# JSON закодированный юникод как расшифровать на DELPHI

Tags: delphi, json, unicode

Пишу парсер ключевых слов из wordstat.yandex.ru

Отправляю POST-запрос, получаю зашифрованный JSON-ответ. Что с ним делать, чтобы превратить в нормальный вид? Вроде как функция приходит вместе с зашифрованным ответом, но как ее использовать? Привожу не полный пример полученного ответа:

```
{"data":"hX8L^^\u0002@[ZUN\\r[\\A\\6V\u0017\fq\u0012\u0004VLGD\\\\LdVVQD\u0003\u0003D\u0004opvStiPGkQ\rLt\u00074P;\u0003\u0018>\u0015Y /ktwrK/OEv`\u000eEWo\u0013g\u0005VMr<|\u0010nDJriwev\u0016'`.QG#]nush\u0006`o\u0017ZD.vT\u000b\\M\u0016qO)J\u001dwGcxg\u0012\u0016Cb\u000e#ki\u00014Dd1bm24\\\u0010Z\u0010%\biwbnoWT0J\u0010 !PshGuTG}V\u0014vq\u0013t\u0003\u001ctuJ>YI.T\n\u0006o\u0015\u0012\u0018dY@TYYA\u0010c\u0005\u0004\u0007\u001c\u0007u\u001c\u0000\nFRV]\u000e_BD\u0005\u001cpw `~PP|Qk[\u0005\u0010j\u0003 \u0016>\u0000\u0014@ \u001a/! rJ\\OD\u0005`xG\u000b3&gsTM\u0002:|fm\b\u001c  F1::\u0002\u0015\u0002\u0013\u0003\u0012\r8\u0014qag\u000bv]#I\u0000C&\u0002\u000e;aX__\u000btWs\br\u0005`VuzC|\u001eInDBdF\u0010mBF\\fYMSy~\u0016a\t\bWGQH\u0006\u001aWFr}QuDP\tC\u0003\u0002\u0010\u0004\u0003K\r\u0005uJI+I^W\n\u0007\u001dH\u0014\u001cfL]&JEE\u0005|gX\u0002\u0006x\u0010\u0005{\u0017\n\u0002\u0012\u0003\u0007\u0019\u0005\u0002Q\u0012\u001d\u0017aSsiPF6W}+c\u0006\u001a\u0014zAh|B@`yvcv\u0015]\\ZRvsoGA.avpC[r\\kbzSA;x\u0000\u0010vg'`XQGS^n\u0003p5p`{vY#I\u0000Gj^[,pY/_\u000bwWt|r\u0005a\u000bs#k\u001esDCdGa0DCKqYwBz\u0016`xUQB1_\u0006 FG\u0001}P\u0004\u0019V\n%\u0014\u0007w\u0013\u0002\u0003\u001c\u0004{\u0003\u001b\u0018\u0019\u0003D\u001cwZYMMr[X\u0016\u000e\u0006\u0006Okgb\u0013\u0007\u000b\u0010\u0004z\u0017\n\u0006\u0012\u0003\u0002\u000fSB\u0011\u0012\u001d\u0017a$wiZEkZzLt\u00036S;\u0007h|C\u001df\tktwf]-XR\u0005uz@Es\u0016pd'X\u0001MmqmQW\u0007|\u0016\u0017\u0015q!uO#'D,{\u0014\u0001\fa\u0010zv(QIvAj._q\u0000ZH8\b\u0010@vo\u0013\u0007w1uiT~\bujS7\u0002P\u0016xU2Lq.\u0004Bu}\u0016\u0016z\b]7Q>\u0004G[C\u0012jP\u0012T&\u001cTr\u0011\u0007\u0004^FTT(\u001d9\b\u001c\u0018\b@[\u000b\u0002\u0012\rd(KQ-RA\u0012k\u0010\u0010\u0013\f\u0010r\t\u0017zq\u0012u\u0004DspDs\u001ep\u0006Q`\bRP\fTk-v\u0010\u001atm3}k3\nqx~c\u0001g],XRvuo1Bs\u0017\u0001d\"X\u0015;lq\u001bPW{}\u0016\u0011bq]\u0003O%SDP}\u0014qaf\tv]#I\u0000C,\u0003\u0006 !\u0004\u0019_\n\u0007Wu\u000br\u0002\u0010Vp\u000eC|\u001fR5\u0018\u0001$\u001b&mBB\\g+\u0010Uiwbn\u0014WTFJ\u0010&RP\u000fhGsQG{S\u0014p\u0005\u0013r\u0004\u001cr|JBZI(Q\nwl\u0015d\u0019rQ-A+FV\u0018|qd\u0006\u0010{\u0005\u0013}\u0003\u001d\f\u0005\u0014pQ\u0014sQ\u0012jdaYpiPEk'~L\u0004s
```

И вот что ещё есть в ответе - полная функция:

```
"key":"var f51 = function(v574){var t594 = \"b7ab\";return function(){return t594.concat(v574)}}(\"41f9\".split('').reverse().join('').concat(185372^678160).substr(0).split('a').join('b'));f51()"}
```

Comment: функция то каждый раз совсем разная, или только  входные параметры? Если алгоритм тот же, то реализуйте его на делфи, а параметры расшифровки (`b7ab`, `41f9` и т.п.) надо дергать из текста приведенной функции

Comment: В получаемом ответе закодированный текст и функция всегда разные, функция генерирует кусочек ключа для расшифровки текста